# How do I fix 'org-reftex-citation: No bibliography defined in file' error?

Tags: bibtex, errors, emacs, org-mode, debian

I am using Debian Wheezy with Emacs24.4.50.1 and Org-Mode 8.2.6. I am using Kieren Healy's Emacs Starter Kit for the Social Science. http://kieranhealy.org/resources/emacs-starter-kit/ With this Starter Kit it is necessary to rename the **kjhealy.org** file and customize things like the bibliography.

I am trying to get my bibliography working in a test document.When I try to insert a reference with **C-c C-x [** I get the error:

```
  org-reftex-citation: No bibliography defined in file
```

The **kjhealy.org** file looks like this:

```
;; Make RefTex able to find my local bib files
(setq reftex-bibpath-environment-variables
'("/Users/kjhealy/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib"))

;; Default bibliography
(setq reftex-default-bibliography
'("/Users/kjhealy/Documents/bibs/socbib.bib"))
```

My username.org looks like this:

```
*** Local RefTeX Settings
Tell RefTeX where the bibliography files are. 

   ;; Make RefTex able to find my local bib files
    (setq reftex-bibpath-environment-variables
    '("/home/username/Dropbox/bibliography/references.bib"))

    ;; Default bibliography
    (setq reftex-default-bibliography
    '("/home/username/Dropbox/bibliography/references.bib"))
```

Kieren Healy is working on a Mac. I suspect I am doing something wrong with the reftex-bibpath-environment-variables. Debian doesn't have 'Library' in the /home directory. I am not sure how to find the /texmf/bibtex/bib folder on Debian or its equivalent.

Any suggestion on how to correct this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian the `texmf` directory is in your home directory: `~/texmf`. I have the following in my `.emacs`:

```el
(setq reftex-default-bibliography 
  '("~/texmf/bibtex/bib/ty2.bib"))

(setq reftex-bibpath-environment-variables
  '("/home/tws/texmf/bibtex/bib/:/home/tws/texmf/bibtex/"))
```

Comment: If there's something wrong with my answer, let me know. Down-voting the only answer to a 6 month old question with no explanation isn't very helpful.